# Passing variable in curlopt_url

Tags: php, json, api, php-curl, postmates

I want to pass a variable in CURLOPT_URL, here is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/cus_KtQih0aARUZXdk/deliveries/$delivery_id/cancel",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'pickup_address' => $_POST["pickup_address"],
    'pickup_phone_number' => $_POST["pickup_phone_number"],
    'pickup_name' => $_POST["pickup_name"],
    'dropoff_address' => $_POST["dropoff_address"],
    'dropoff_phone_number' => $_POST["dropoff_phone_number"],
    'dropoff_name' => $_POST["dropoff_name"],
    'manifest' => $_POST["manifest"]        
  ),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic MjhiMDU0ODktNjdkYS00M2VhLTg0NmMtYWQ1MWQ2MGNmMDA1Og==",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$delivery_id = trim($_POST['show_name']);

curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($response);
$timestamp = json_decode($dateJSON, true);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response->fee;
}
```

I want to add the variable `$delivery_id` in the url, but I am not too familiar with cURL and the above written code is not working. Please show me the way to include this variable in my url.

Comment: What is the error you getting? are your indices quoted?

Comment: Your code looks fine - what is the error you get? If no error, what is the output of die($response);

Comment: The error message I am getting is : The requested endpoint could not be found.

Comment: No Matter what never reveal authorization headers in content. And what is the value of $delivery_id, try printing that.

Comment: Let me clarify, the endpoint format is like : https://www.example.com/deliveries/:delivery_id/cancel  and I am using a variable $delivery_id here. when I am trying to echo $delivery_id its giving correct response, something like del_Ky3hw6Q50YUCdk

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same error. The solution is : **use** **'** -*apostrophe* - and **.** -*dot*- before and after the variable. Like this:

> ### /deliveries/**'.$delivery_id.'**/cancel